# Passing string to a different view controller through accessoryButton returns null

Tags: ios, string, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UITableViewController` "FirstViewController" and cells with accessory view buttons. I am using the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath delegate method to set some string values when a row is selected. Then there is a transition through storyboard to a new `UIViewController` and I am trying to set this string as text to a `UILabel`. However in the new view controller the string returns null, it is not retained. The second view controller is designed in storyboard. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

FirstViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titlelbl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * atitle;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.atitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[alltitles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1]]; // this string returns a proper value
    NSLog(@"%@", self.atitle);

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"articles"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@synthesize atitle;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    FirstViewController * irstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.atitle = self.atitle;  // the string returns null. it does not retain the value from the first view controller
    self.titlelbl.text = self.atitle;
    self.sourcelbl.text = @"Source:";
    NSLog(@"%@", self.atitle);
}
```

Comment: Try using self.storyboard instead...is the current view controller on the storyboard as well?

Comment: @Jacob Yes. The transition takes place properly

Comment: You're doing this completely wrong. You should be setting the value of a string property that you have in the 2nd controller inside accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:. Alloc init'ing a new instance of FirstViewController (not the one you came from) in viewDidLoad is just plain useless. There are thousands of answers about passing data from one controller to another on SO, so please search them.

Comment: @rdelmar I have tried both ways. It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your FirstViewController is setting the param value in itself:

```
self.atitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[alltitles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1]]; // this string returns a proper value
```

Your SecondViewController seems to be reading the same value from itself ..

```
firstViewController.atitle = self.atitle;  // the string returns null. it does not retain the value from the first view controller
```

Also when you alloc a new FirstViewController. You are looking at a brand new object so aTitle on that object is not the same as from the new one.

You will have to set the aTitle on the secondviewcontroller.

Also recommend using segues in this case.

Comment: This is not the problem. I just made a string in the second view controller with the same name and assigned the value to it.

Comment: I am not getting confused because of the same name. Look at your code above. In FirstViewController.m you set the atitle

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.atitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[alltitles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1]]; // this string returns a proper value
Then you are looking at self.atitle in SecondViewController.m..  see my point?

Comment: I do not really get what you mean.

Comment: look at your code carefully. the place you are assigning atitle first is in FirstViewController.m right? the place where you are trying to use it is in SecondViewController.h where you are using self.atitle. How can you expect this value to be set when you have only set it on the FirstViewController so far?

Comment: I have set it in the second one as well, I just didn't include it in the code here. There would be an error if I didn't include it. I tried to alloc the second view controller to the first one instead and set the string value from there, but still it didn't work